# how to connect 2 networks with different routers

Tags: networking, router, local-area-network

I have a TP-Link TL-ER6120 VPN router and a Cisco RV-180 VPN router. I want to have 2 networks with two routers connecting each other. My network is the following:

Internet -----> TL-ER6120 (192.168.1.2) -------> Swich (LAN 192.168.1.0/24)

I want to have the following if it is possible:

Internet-----> TL-ER6120 (192.168.1.2) -------> Swith (LAN 192.168.1.0/24)

```
                      |
                      |
                      |
           Cisco RV180 (192.168.2.1) ------> Switch (LAN 192.168.2.0/24)
```

The LAN 192.168.2.0 must have internet access.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with routing.  The network is so small, you might even just do static routing, but any supported routing protocols like RIP, EIGRP, OSPF, etc. would do the trick.  The main points to hit on:

- The connection between routers should be its own subnet, such as 192.168.3.0/24, and each router's interface must have an address in the subnet.  You might also need a crossover cable for this connection.
- 192.168.2.0/24 must be advertised on the inter-router interface of the Cisco, or else statically set
- The upstream interface of the Cisco should be the default route (0.0.0.0/0)

You have not given enough details for a full plan here, such as whether 192.168.1.0/24 should be able to reach the Internet, or even be able to talk to 192.168.2.0/24.

Comment: Hi armani, yes both need access to the internet and talk to each other. 192.168.1.0/24 already have access to the internet . I just want to add the 192.168.2.0/24 network. The problem that I have is that these router aren't like the enterprise class routers like cisco, where I can do that with console (IOS). These router have web interface and does not come with console ports (just the TP-Link router). should I connec each ther using the WAN Port or LANS Ports?